Maximal number of independent vectors in a Boolean space
Consider the set of length $n$ Boolean vectors, with addition defined as component-wise OR, and multiplication by a boolean scalar value defined by component-wise AND with that scalar, as expected.
Consider a subset $S$ of such vectors such that no vector in $S$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the remaining ones.
Question : What is the maximum size of $S$ , or a meaningful upper bound thereof, expressed as a function of $n$?
Said in other words : What is the maximum size of a family $F$ of subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$ such that no element in $F$ can be expressed as the union of the others?

We know that there are $2^n$ Bit Patterns with $n$ Binary Digits.
These are Binary Numbers $0$ to $2^n-1$.
In  that , we can choose those Patterns which have $n/2$ "On" & $n$ "Off".
It is easy to check that union of 2 such vectors will have at least 1 more "On" , hence there is no repetition.
We have $^{n}P_{n/2}$ vectors.
Now , we can exclude 1 vector $0\cdots01\cdots1$ & then consider the smaller case with $n/4$ "On" (Binary Numbers $0$ to $2^{n/2}-1$) & $3n/4$ "Off".
We have $^{n/2}P_{n/4}$ vectors.
Similarly , we can exclude 1 vector $0\cdots010\cdots010\cdots01\cdots1$ & then consider the smaller case with $n/8$ "On" (Binary Numbers $0$ to $2^{n/4}-1$) & $7n/8$ "Off".
We have $^{n/4}P_{n/8}$ vectors.
Proceeding like this will give maximal Bit Patterns where union can not generate other Bit Patterns.

Hello. Not sure I understood your answer, as you seem to assume that all of B1,B2,B3
are in S
, which is not a hypothesis. For example, consider S
consisting of (1,0,0), (1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1).

Oh , I did not get your Question right earlier ! I updated the Answer now , @Michele , let me know whether that is matching what you were looking for & I will include the Calculations & Examples !
